# How to default a Django DateTimeField to utcnow() + 1 day?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django object that looks like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

class MyObject:
    startTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

Now I want to add a field to this model called expiredTime that is automatically set to 1 day after the startTime. Obviously this won't work:

```
    expiredTS = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow + timedelta(days=1))
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a function to produce the default:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def utc_tomorrow():
    return datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)

class MyObject:
    startTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    expiredTS = models.DateTimeField(default=utc_tomorrow)
```

Each time a default is needed, the `default` callable is called; each time the `utc_tomorrow` function is called the expression is executed and a new datetime object is generated one day in the future.

For Django versions before 1.7, you could also use a `lambda` for this, but changes in migration serialization now require a global object.

Comment: Didn't work: Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @SaqibAli: how are you importing `datetime` and `timedelta`?

Comment: Like this: `import datetime, timedelta`

Comment: @SaqibAli: `timedelta` is not a module in the Python standard library. You need to use the `datetime.timedelta` object. I've added an import statement to my answer.

Comment: I think `lambda:` stopped working in django models (if it worked before)  I get `File "C:\Python\34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\serializer.py", line 163, in serialize
    raise ValueError("Cannot serialize function: lambda")`

Comment: @BronDavies: make it a separate function, see [How to set a Django model field's default value to a function call / callable (e.g., a date relative to the time of model object creation)](//stackoverflow.com/q/12649659)